# Delete all rows in an HTML table except for header with JS

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

So I am having trouble deleting all of the data in an HTML table with js WITHOUT deleting the header. Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<title>Z80 Opcodes</title>
<body>
<input type="text" id = "input" value = "">
<button onClick = "hex()">Hex</button>
<button onClick = "bin()">Bin</button>
<button onClick = "assem()">Assembly</button>
<button onClick = "find()">Find</button>
<table id = "out" style="width:100%">
<thead>
<th align="left">Binary</th>
<th align="left">Hex</th>
<th align="left">Assembly</th>
<th align="left">Description</th>
</thead>
<tbody id="tb">
</tbody>
<script src = "js/script.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is script.js:

```
var id = document.getElementById("out");
var ab = "";
var row;
var table = ['0000000000nopno operation', '0000000101ld (bc), **loads ** into BC'];
var bin = ['00000000', '00000001'];
var hex = ['00', '01'];
var assembly = ['nop', 'ld (bc), **'];
var description = ['no operation', 'loads ** into BC'];
l = table.length;
function find() {
    row = id.insertRow(0);
    for (i=0;i <=l-1;i++) {
        ab = table[i];
        if (ab.includes(document.getElementById("input").value)) {
            row = id.insertRow(-1);
            cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            cell1.innerHTML = bin[i];
            cell2.innerHTML = hex[i];
            cell3.innerHTML = assembly[i];
            cell4.innerHTML = description[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I have omitted A LOT of array entries because they contained almost the FULL instruction set of thee z80 microprocessor.
What this code does (basically) is it gets an input from the user and if the array `table` contains that input then it gets the corresponding values from `bin`, `hex`, `assembly` and `description` and assigns each a column in the table `out`, then adds a row with the for the data. However, I cannot seem to find a way to delete all of the rows in `tbody` before another set of values are appended to the table without deleting `thead`. I have searched around on the web and found several solutions, none of which worked. They either deleted the `thead` or caused some kind of error (I'll give examples if you ask). I am using Google Chrome version 63.0.3239.132 web browser to run my code.
As you may be able to see I am quite new to js and HTML
Any ideas what I have done wrong?

~Jachdich

Comment: `document.querySelector('#out tbody').remove()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First You have to close your `<table>` tag `</table>`

This is how you can clear your table.

```js
$('#remove').on('click', ()=>{
   $('#tb').empty()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id = "out" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
          <th align="left">Binary</th>
          <th align="left">Hex</th>
          <th align="left">Assembly</th>
          <th align="left">Description</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tb">
        <tr>
            <th>01010101</th>
            <th>1231:sdf:sdf42</th>
            <th>213123</th>
            <th>description</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>   

<button id="remove">
  clear
</button>
```

Comment: I had a bit of a formatting error, the `</table>` tag is in my code, I must have deleted it in the question by accident

Comment: I hope this snippet can help you :)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to keep the tbody element intact instead of just removing it and all its children at once:

```
// get a reference to the tbody element
var tb = document.querySelector('#out tbody');

// while tb has children, remove the first one
while (tb.childNodes.length) {
  tb.removeChild(tb.childNodes[0]);
}
// tb is now empty
```

Answer (score 1):

From a semantic perspective, it would make the removal of rows much easier if you added them to the `<tbody>` element instead of the `<thead>` element. This way, you could target the rows within the body and remove them whilst preserving your `<thead>` (sibling node to ):

```
var body = document.querySelector('tbody');
while (body.firstChild) {
  // This will remove all children within tbody which in your case are <tr> elements
  body.removeChild(body.firstChild);
}
```

body.removeChild(rowsWithinBody)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody#examples

Comment: querySelector returns the FIRST element matching the selector so this would only remove the first row

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery you can do it simply in a single line of code.

> $("#table_id tbody tr").remove();

it will remove all rows in a table except the header.